# Downloaded laravel project hangs on preloader when deployed on localhost

Tags: laravel, localhost, homestead

I'm trying to deploy a laravel project I have received onto my localhost but it hangs on the loading page and doesn't load the site.

I received the source code of a laravel project that was coded for me.
The deployed website on the shared hosting works properly, and I can also manipulate the files through my ftp access.
However, I'm trying to deploy the project on my localhost (as well as to migrate to a different shared hosting service).

I tried loading the server on wamp, homestead and with artisan serve, but all methods end up the same - the index.php seems to be loading, but is stuck eternally on the preloading .gif file and doesn't present the site.
the browser debugger is throwing a lot of javascript errors (see attached image)

I assume a have a config problem, but I can't locate it and I am unsure how to even locate & debug the issue.

I tried following these configuration steps:
1.  changed .htaccess to generic laravel .htaccess (deleted cpanel related lines)
2. changed the .env to fit my wamp db / homestead db
3. composer install
4. composer update
5. php artisan key:generate
6. php artisan cache:clear
7. php artisan migrate

I also installed laravel-debugbar but it hasn't helped me out of the box, and I'm unsure where I need to try to catch the problem.
If anyone can give me pointers on how to understand my problem better, I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance!

[laravel bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFUeZ.jpg)

Comment: You've got JavaScript errors that are probably preventing the preloader from saying "yup, everything's loaded OK". I don't see anything in there that looks like a Laravel issue. Whatever that "revolution" extension is, it's not loading right.

Comment: (Maybe you need to do an `npm install` or something, or run an asset compilation script?)

Comment: @ceejayoz Okay that makes sense! thanks for the info. revolution seems to be a slider app that's installed in my theme. [link](https://revolution.themepunch.com/) I'm guessing it's not compiled properly, I tried `npm install` as well as `npm run dev` and the rest of the steps as mentioned below by @emotality , however the issue persists.
What do you mean by asset compilation script? how would I get one for this extension? thanks!

Comment: @ceejayoz I finally figured out how to remove the plugin from my page (foolish me, I forgot to look for the <script> in the main layout file) and it was indeed the problem! now only to figure out how to recomplile it to work...

Answer (score 0):

- Double check your `.env` if all details are correct
- Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file
- Double check if your database exist and have data if you are using a database
- Check if your host is added to `/etc/hosts`
- Check if your host is added to apache/nginx config correctly

Try running these commands:

```
$ rm composer.lock package-lock.json
$ composer install
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
$ php artisan clear-compiled
$ php artisan optimize:clear
$ php artisan package:discover
$ php artisan storage:link
$ php artisan migrate:fresh && php artisan db:seed // optional!
```

Then clear browser cache to be safe.

Open web inspector to see if you can see any errors.
Open latest laravel log in `storage/logs/` folder to debug.

If all fails, install [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see if you can debug there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Connection to the database etc. was okay. I figured out that the problem was a defective plugin on my page(revolution slider). I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work though, and figure I need to recompile it or something. I thought that's what `npm install` `npm run dev` do, but unfortunatly this didn't solve the issue :(